# How to change labels (legends) in ggplot?

Tags: r, math, plot, ggplot2, statistics

My code is like below, I want to change the label of the ggplot, but R always remind me:

```
Error in unit(tic_pos.c, "mm") : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0
```

What should I do?

```
ggplot(mat,aes(x=sales,col=type))+
  geom_density()+labels("red_sold","blue_sold","yellow_sold")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is `mat$type` a factor? If not, that will cause the error. Also, you can't use `labels(...)` this way.

Since you did not provide any data, here's an example using the built-in `mtcars` dataset.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp,color=factor(cyl)))+
  geom_density()+
  scale_color_manual(name="Cylinders",
                       labels=c("4 Cylinder","6 Cylinder","8- Cylinder"),
                       values=c("red","green","blue"))
```

[image]

In this example,

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp,color=cyl))+...
```

would cause the same error that you are getting, because `mtcars$cyl` is not a factor.

Comment: Of note, it is possible to change `name` and `labels` with keeping the defaults `values` by using `scale_color_discrete()` instead.

Comment: @DanChaltiel Maybe you could post your comment as a regular answer, so it's easier to find?

Answer (score 11):

As a complement to @jlhoward's answer, `scale_color_manual()` is more intended to customize the color scale (the actual colors that will be displayed).

For your case, you might rather use `scale_color_discrete()`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp,color=factor(cyl)))+
    geom_density()+
    scale_color_discrete(name="Cylinders",
                         labels=c("4 Cylinder","6 Cylinder","8- Cylinder"))
```

This is quicker, but it is dependant on the factor levels order, which might lead to irreproducibility. You might want to specify the `breaks` argument to minimise the risk of error (and customize the order in the legend):

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp,color=factor(cyl)))+
    geom_density()+
    scale_color_discrete(name="Cylinders",
                         breaks=c(8,6,4),
                         labels=c("8 Cylinder","6 Cylinder","4 Cylinder"))
```

More info on https://ggplot2-book.org/scales.html.